# Shiny App Working locally but Package Issue/conflict on Deployment

Tags: r, shiny

Good Afternoon,

I'm running into an issue.  My app is running fine locally but when I go to publish i get this response.  I also attached a copy of the logs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9oRJ.png)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you deploying the app?

Comment: On Shiny Server.

Comment: Shinyapps.io.  Have you heard of it?

Comment: Check out this article for troubleshooting: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-

Comment: I read that among other things.  I'm really looking for more of a definitive, "Oh I've experienced that.  This is the fix."

Comment: You don't give much information. Those are just warnings. There are several possible reasons that could explain why your app is not working on the server. Does it work when you run your app on the server with the rstudio server (if installed)?

Comment: Thanks Mlavoie.  Yep.  It works on locally via R Studio.  But when I try to publish what you see above returns.